Why won't my next.js credentials login with email and password work while my google provider authentication does?
I am trying to make a login page with Next Auth V4, and I have followed some instructions online that seems to work well for the google provider which works, but my "credentials" email and password login does not seem to be working.
I think it potentially has something to do with 2 different areas, the "strategy" under the "session" options, and the callbacks.
For the callbacks area, probably the most likely issue, simply seems to be the fact that the callbacks don't seem to be called when I do email and password login with my database, which I am using elephantsql postgresql free tier, and prisma as well. When I do google provider login, it gets called and I have console logged session and user, but I have not been able to recreate it with email.
For the session/ strategy area, when I leave it blank, my google provider works, but when I set strategy to JWT, google provider stops working. For some reason, once, and only once, when I set it to JWT it seemed my email login seemed to work, but I have not been able to recreate it after I commented it out to get my google provider back up and running, even when I un-commented it out and tried it again.
Registration page has no issues, I can see in the databse my email and password
Here is my api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts
import { mergeAnonymousCartIntoUserCart } from "@/lib/db/cart";
import prisma from "@/lib/db/prisma";
import { env } from "@/lib/env";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import { Adapter } from "next-auth/adapters";
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import Google from "next-auth/providers/google";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import InstagramProvider from "next-auth/providers/instagram";
import { compare } from "bcrypt";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  session: {
    // strategy: "jwt",               <===== When Set, breaks google provider.
  },                          <==== somehow worked once when set, but just once

  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma as PrismaClient) as Adapter,
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",                 <====== where I am sending people for my login page 
  },
  providers: [
    Google({
      clientId: env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,           <== Seems to Work when JWT strategy not set
      clientSecret: env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    InstagramProvider({
      clientId: process.env.INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,       <== Not Implemented, 
      clientSecret: process.env.INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: {},
        password: {},
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            email: credentials?.email,
          },
        });

        let passwordCorrect = false;
        if (user?.password) {
          passwordCorrect = await compare(
            credentials?.password || "",
            user?.password,
          );
        }

        if (passwordCorrect) {
          return user;
        }
        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    session({ session, user }) { <=== prints out with google provider but not credentials
      console.log(session, "///////////////////////////////session");
      console.log(user, "----------------------------------user");
      session.user.id = user.id;
      return session;
    },
  },
  events: {
    async signIn({ user }) {
      await mergeAnonymousCartIntoUserCart(user.id);
    },
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };


here is /login/page.tsx
import Form from "./Form";

export default function LoginPage() {
  return <Form />;
}


and here is the login/Form.tsx page
"use client";

import Image from "next/image";
import googleLogo from "@/assets/googleLogo.svg";
import redditLogo from "@/assets/redditLogo.svg";
import instagramLogo from "@/assets/instagramLogo.svg";
import facebookLogo from "@/assets/facebookLogo.svg";
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";
import { FormEvent } from "react";

export default function Form() {
  const handleSubmit = async (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget);
    const resp = signIn("credentials", {
      email: formData.get("email"),
      password: formData.get("password"),
      redirect: false,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex h-96 items-center justify-center pt-24">
      <div className="card w-96 content-center bg-base-100 shadow-xl">
        <div className="card-body">
          <div className="flex flex-row justify-between">
            <span className="divider w-20" />
            <h1 className="card-title justify-center">Login Here</h1>
            <span className="divider w-20" />
          </div>
          <form className="max-w-md items-center" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label className="input input-bordered mb-2 flex items-center">
              <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                fill="currentColor"
                className="h-4 w-4 opacity-70"
              >
                <path d="M2.5 3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 4.5v.793c.026.009.051.02.076.032L7.674 8.51c.206.1.446.1.652 0l6.598-3.185A.755.755 0 0 1 15 5.293V4.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 13.5 3h-11Z" />
                <path d="M15 6.954 8.978 9.86a2.25 2.25 0 0 1-1.956 0L1 6.954V11.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 13h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5V6.954Z" />
              </svg>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="grow"
                name="email"
                placeholder=" Email"
              />
            </label>
            <label className="input input-bordered mb-2 flex items-center">
              <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                fill="currentColor"
                className="h-4 w-4 opacity-70"
              >
                <path
                  fillRule="evenodd"
                  d="M14 6a4 4 0 0 1-4.899 3.899l-1.955 1.955a.5.5 0 0 1-.353.146H5v1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-2a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-2.293a.5.5 0 0 1 .146-.353l3.955-3.955A4 4 0 1 1 14 6Zm-4-2a.75.75 0 0 0 0 1.5.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5.75.75 0 0 0 1.5 0 2 2 0 0 0-2-2Z"
                  clipRule="evenodd"
                />
              </svg>
              <input
                type="password"
                className="grow"
                placeholder=" Enter Password"
                name="password"
              />
            </label>
            <div className="flex justify-center">
              <button
                id="submit"
                type="submit"
                className="btn mt-4 min-w-[200px] rounded-full bg-primary"
              >
                Login
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
          <div className="flex flex-row justify-between">
            <span className="divider w-24" />
            <h4 className="card-title justify-center">Or With</h4>
            <span className="divider w-24" />
          </div>
          <div className="card-actions justify-center gap-6">
            <Image
              src={googleLogo}
              alt="google login logo"
              height={45}
              width={45}
              onClick={() => signIn("google")}
            />
            <Image
              src={instagramLogo}
              alt="google login logo"
              height={45}
              width={45}
              onClick={() => signIn("instagrams")}
            />
            <Image
              src={facebookLogo}
              alt="google login logo"
              height={45}
              width={45}
              onClick={() => signIn("google")}
            />
            <Image
              src={redditLogo}
              alt="google login logo"
              height={45}
              width={45}
              onClick={() => signIn("google")}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


Here is my Schema in my prisma.schema file. A lot I got from the next auth documentation. Even though I seem to be using sessions, they do not seem to be saved in the database. Even for the google provider ones that seem to actually work.

model Product {
  id          String     @id @default(cuid())
  name        String     @db.VarChar(127)
  description String     @db.VarChar(511)
  imageUrl    String     @db.VarChar(255)
  price       Int        @db.SmallInt
  createdAt   DateTime   @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime   @updatedAt
  CartItem    CartItem[]

  @@map("products")
}

model Cart {
  id        String     @id @default(cuid())
  items     CartItem[]
  userId    String?
  user      User?      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  createdAt DateTime   @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime   @updatedAt

  @@map("carts")
}

model CartItem {
  id        String  @id @default(cuid())
  productId String
  product   Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  quantity  Int
  cartId    String
  cart      Cart    @relation(fields: [cartId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@map("cartItems")
}

model User {
  id            String          @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String          @unique
  password      String?
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
  // Optional for WebAuthn support
  Authenticator Authenticator[]

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  Cart      Cart[]

  @@map("users")
}

model Account {
  userId            String
  type              String
  provider          String
  providerAccountId String
  refresh_token     String?
  access_token      String?
  expires_at        Int?
  token_type        String?
  scope             String?
  id_token          String?
  session_state     String?

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@id([provider, providerAccountId])
  @@map("accounts")
}

model Session {
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       String
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  @@map("sessions")
}

model VerificationToken {
  identifier String
  token      String
  expires    DateTime

  @@id([identifier, token])
  @@map("verificationtokens")
}

// Optional for WebAuthn support
model Authenticator {
  credentialID         String  @unique
  userId               String
  providerAccountId    String
  credentialPublicKey  String
  counter              Int
  credentialDeviceType String
  credentialBackedUp   Boolean
  transports           String?

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@id([userId, credentialID])
  @@map("authenticators")
}


